# Computing value using pgfmath for use in coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, pgfmath

Why can't I use the outcome of using pgfmath in a TikZ coordinate?

Here is a (minimal) example that does not work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\leftBoundary}{\pgfmathparse{0.255in*3/2}\pgfmathresult}

% This is fine:
\node at (0,0) {\leftBoundary};

% This does not work:
\draw[thick] (\leftBoundary,2) rectangle +(1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to compute a number of dimensions that I then use for arranging things in a figure. While I know that I could also use code like `($(point1)+(3,4)$)` during drawing stuff in TikZ, for better overview, it would be great if the dimensions can be computed upfront.

Comment: If you take the `pgfmathparse` out from the command definition, the rest would work just fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, that doesn’t work because TikZ only accepts fully expandable input.

By the way, the coordinate input is thrown into PGF math anyway, so

```
\draw[thick] (0.255in*3/2,2) …
```

works just as well (case 1).

You can also just store `0.255in*3/2` in `\leftBoundary` and use that macro (case 2; again, using that anything will be parsed through the mathematical engine of PGF anyway).

Of course, for very exhausting calculation or for often-used values, you may pre-calculate some values beforehand and use the parsed and calculated result.

For this, you will need to use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\leftBoundary{0.255in*3/2}
```

(case 3) or

```
\pgfmathparse{0.255in*3/2}\let\leftBoundary\pgfmathresult
```

(which is more or less the same thing as long as the result is a number).

Both will set `\leftBoundary` to the resulting value in `pt` but without a unit. TikZ will then interprets this value in the standard user coordinate system, which suddenly makes your TikZ picture nearly 28 cm wide. You will need to append `pt` again in the path.

Very helpful here is (besides using a real TeX dimension, case 5) the macro `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` which appends `pt` to the resulting value on its own (case 4).

---

You might wonder why I used a `+` in the cases 3, 4 and 5. As said at the beginning, TikZ throws most of its input through PGF math anyway.

A preceeding `+` though will disable the math parsing “and a simple assignment or increment is done using normal TeX assignments or increments. This will be orders of magnitude faster than calling the parser.” ([PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), v 2.10, section 62.1 “Commands for Parsing Expressions”, p. 527)

For cases 3 and 4 this can be applied because `\leftBoundary` contains only `27.6438pt`, in case 5 `\leftBoundary` is actually a dimension (length) and is made for TeX’s assignments.

Preceeding a `+` in cases 1 and 2 will result in typesetting `*3/2` in the TikZ picture as `0.255in` is a legal TeX assignment:

[image]

Using `+3/2*0.255in` (which would have been legal in PGF math) will result in an error from TeX.

How much this actually matter (in terms of compilation time), I never have tested it thoroughly.

When in doubt,
  leave it out.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}\tikzset{every picture/.append style={framed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\draw[thick] (0.255in*3/2,2) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway] {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand*{\leftBoundary}{0.255in*3/2}
\node at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\draw[thick] (\leftBoundary,2) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway] {2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\leftBoundary{0.255in*3/2}
\node at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\draw[thick] (+\leftBoundary pt,2) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway] {3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\leftBoundary{0.255in*3/2}
\node at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\draw[thick] (+\leftBoundary,2) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway] {4};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newdimen\leftBoundary % or \newlength\leftBoundary
\pgfmathsetlength\leftBoundary{0.255in*3/2}
\node at (0,0) {$(0,0)$};
\draw[thick] (+\leftBoundary,2) rectangle +(1,1) node[midway] {5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (Example)

[image]

Comment: Indeed. Great explanation! So the input to tikz for coordinates has to be fully expandable. In any case, "\pgfmathsetlengthmacro" seems to be the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: What about allowing arguments to `pgfsetmacro`?