# How to draw a circle whose radius is a multiple of the distance of two points in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following is the MWE for my figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[b]
   \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]           
       \coordinate (a) at (1,4);
       \coordinate (p) at (1,5);

       \draw(a) let \p1 = ($ (a) - (p) $) in circle (\pgfmathparse{veclen(\x1,\y1) * 3}\pgfmathresult);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting the following error for this:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 12.
```

I'm not sure what is the issue here - some help would be appreciated!

Comment: Related: [Computing value using pgfmath for use in coordinates?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112457)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need the `\pgfmathparse..\pgfmathresult`. Note the extra pair of brackets around the calculation in the code below, which hides the parenthesis of the `veclen` function from the delimiters of the circle radius.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \coordinate (a) at (1,4);
       \coordinate (p) at (1,5);
       \draw(a) let \p1 = ($ (a) - (p) $) in
         circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)*3});

       \fill (a) circle[radius=1pt] node[right]{a};
       \fill (p) circle[radius=1pt] node[right]{p};       
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 7):

Do not use `\pgfmathparse` in coordinates or other values of TikZ.

TikZ will parse nearly everything through PGF math anyway which is also the reason it doesn’t work because you can’t use content that is not fully expandable.

You could have used

```
\draw(a) let \p1 = ($ (a) - (p) $) in \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{veclen(\x1,\y1) * 3}}
                                                          circle [radius=\pgfmathresult pt];
```

but others have already given better solutions than that.

---

I want to propose another option: the `through` library.

It has only one purpose: drawing a circle through on specific point. With the `calc` library you can now write

```
\node[draw] at (a) [circle through=($(a)!3!(p)$)] {};
```

with the same effect.

Without the `calc` library, this can be reduced to

```
\node[draw] at (a) [circle through=(p), scale=3] {};
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, dot/.style={shape=circle,inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2pt, fill, label={#1}}]
       \coordinate[dot=a] (a) at (1,4);
       \coordinate[dot=p] (p) at (1,7);

       \foreach \cnt[count=\Cnt] in {.25, .5, 1, 1.5, 2}
         \node[draw, color=red!\Cnt 0!blue, label={[inner sep=+1pt, red!\Cnt 0!blue]below:$ f = \cnt$}] at (a) [circle through=($(a)!\cnt!(p)$)] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, dot/.style={shape=circle,inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2pt, fill, label={#1}}]
       \coordinate[dot=a] (a) at (1,4);
       \coordinate[dot=p] (p) at (1,5);

       \node[draw] at (a) [circle through=(p), scale=3] {};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: To me, the syntax '($(a)!3!(p)$)' is hardly the preferred solution, as its not very readable - the solution without the calc library is more readable IMHO. Perhaps, if you explain the syntax of the calc version, it would be more intuitive?

Comment: @TCSGrad I agree, `calc`’s syntax often times is too short. Though, this is relatively easy: The coordinate is three times away from `a` as `p`. `(a)!0!(p)` gives you `a`, `(a)!1!(p)` gives you `p` and `(a)!.5!(p)` gives you the point that is halfway between `a` and `p`. This syntax is described in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), subsection 13.5.3 “The Syntax of Partway Modiers” (pp. 139ff). I prefer the `calc`-less solution because you do not have to specify the center point `a` twice.

Answer (score 6):

Since you already used `let..in` syntax in your code, why not continue using that syntax to compute the required radius (storing it in, say `\n1`) instead of using `\pgfmathparse/\pgfmathresult`?

I mean the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}          
  \coordinate (a) at (1,4);
  \coordinate (p) at (1,5);
  \foreach \p in {a,p} \fill[red] (\p) circle(1mm);

  \draw[very thick]  
     let \p1 = ($ (a) - (p) $),  
         \n1 = {3*veclen(\x1,\y1)}
     in (a) circle (\n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

With PSTricks

### Single

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){X}(0,2){Y}
    \pstCircleOA[DistCoef=2,Radius=\pstDistAB{X}{Y}]{X}{<ignored>}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Multiple

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\multido{\r=.5+.1}{15}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pstGeonode(0,0){X}(0,2){Y}
    \pstCircleOA[DistCoef=\r,Radius=\pstDistAB{X}{Y}]{X}{<ignored>}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tsunami propagation in action...