# Numbering nodes based on calculation in a for loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, foreach, node-connections

This may be one duplicate of this [QA](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132991/308105). But I failed to use its [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132991/308105).

Here is my example code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}

\newcommand*{\xMin}{0}%
\newcommand*{\xMax}{4}%
\newcommand*{\yMin}{0}%
\newcommand*{\yMax}{3}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \foreach \i in {\xMin,...,\numexpr\xMax-1\relax} {
  \foreach \j[evaluate={\index=\i+4*\j}] in {\yMin,...,\numexpr\yMax-1\relax} {
        \FPadd\xcoord{\i}{0.5}
        \FPadd\ycoord{\j}{0.5}
        \node (\index) at (\xcoord,\ycoord) {a};
        }
    }
    \filldraw (0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it will fail at `\filldraw (0) circle (3pt);` with the error message "Package pgf Error: No shape named `0' is known."

Q:

Are there some errors when I follow the answer referred to?

Comment: You probably want or expect `\index` to be an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fp}
\newcommand*{\xMin}{0}
\newcommand*{\xMax}{4}
\newcommand*{\yMin}{0}
\newcommand*{\yMax}{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {\xMin,...,\numexpr\xMax-1\relax} {
\foreach \j[evaluate={\index=int(\i+4*\j)}] in {\yMin,...,\numexpr\yMax-1\relax} {
\FPadd\xcoord{\i}{0.5}
\FPadd\ycoord{\j}{0.5}
\node (\index) at (\xcoord,\ycoord) {\index}; %changed to show \index
}}
\filldraw (0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 4x3 grid with numbers and a circle]

Comment: Thanks. I should have shown `\index` to see what may be wrong.

Comment: Nowadays one could use `\fpeval`