# \pgfmath and \foreach in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

I am quite new to TikZ. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:1.5)},
                    regular/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=4mm}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,11}
  \node [on chain, regular] (\i) {\i};
\foreach \i in {0,...,11}
  \draw [->] (\i) to ({\pgfmathparse{int(mod(\i+1,12))}\pgfmathresult});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I intended to do is to draw a series of 12 nodes evenly placed on a circle, and draw an arrow between every two neighbors. LaTeX gave an error message saying

```
!incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after ...
```

What is the correct way to do what I intended?

Comment: That's not the only error I get. The first one I get has to do with `\tikzchaincount` which doesn't seem to be defined...

Comment: One problem might be the missing space between `circled placed{at`: that should be `circled placed {at` I think.

Comment: @Jubobs, thanks for pointing out the missed space. I must have accidentally deleted the space while formatting the code for here.

Comment: This has been discussed on TeX.sx before: [Numbering nodes in a for loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132982) and [How to draw a circle whose radius is a multiple of the distance of two points in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129606) and [Computing value using pgfmath for use in coordinates?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112457)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using macros in node names, the macros have to be expandable in an `\edef` context.  `\pgfmathparse` is not.  So you need to do the computation beforehand and only use the result of it in the node name.  One way is to use the `evaluate` key on the `\foreach` as in the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141259/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:1.5)},regular/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=4mm}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,11}
  \node [on chain, regular] (\i) {\i};
\foreach[evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(mod(\i+1,12))}] \i in {0,...,11}
  \draw [->] (\i) to (\ni);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: circular nodes]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[arrows=->,radius=12pt](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{360}{2.5 t 90 add PtoC}{P}% 90 is an angular offset
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\Cnodeput(P\i){A\i}{\i}}
    \Cnodeput(P\Pnodecount){A\Pnodecount}{}
    \multido{\ix=0+1,\iy=1+1}{\Pnodecount}{\ncline{A\ix}{A\iy}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Animation

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\multido{\iN=4+1}{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[arrows=->,radius=12pt](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\iN]{0}{360}{2.5 t 90 add PtoC}{P}% 90 is an angular offset
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\Cnodeput(P\i){A\i}{\i}}
    \Cnodeput(P\Pnodecount){A\Pnodecount}{}
    \multido{\ix=0+1,\iy=1+1}{\Pnodecount}{\ncline{A\ix}{A\iy}}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `curvepnodes` is defined in `pst-node` while `plotpoints` is defined in `pst-plot`. We have to load both packages when using `curvepnodes`,  is it funny?