# Name of shapes defined in an array

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I am trying to use labels defined in an array using tikz for drawing a path between two shapes. I have tried to use `pgfmathparse` but it seems not well defined for string. My syntax is probably wrong.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\stA {AA}
\def\stB {BB}
\def\stC{{"AA","BB"}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (AA){coucou};
\node at (2,0) (BB){ahah};

\draw (\stA)--(\stB);

\draw (\pgfmathparse{\stC[2]}\pgfmathresult)--(\pgfmathparse{\stC[1]}\pgfmathresult);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can not understand, what you like to achieve. For connecting two shapes it is sufficient to say: `\node (AA) at (0,0) {coucou}; \node (BB) at (2,0)  {ahah}; \draw (AA) -- (BB);` Syntax of this lines in your MWE is wrong as well second line with `\draw`, where you use TikZ math engine. What is purpose of this line?

Comment: I use an external script based on MATLAB for generating the connections of my graph. Thus I define an array of the connections.

Comment: Meanwhile I seen from both answers, what is the intention of question. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two methods. The first one use `\pgfextra` to evaluate the array before to use `\pgfmathresult`. The second use `math` library to evaluate the array.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
  \def\stC{{"AA","BB"}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (AA){coucou};
    \node at (2,0) (BB){ahah};
    \draw (AA)--(BB);

    % method one
    \draw[red,bend left] \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{\stC[0]}}(\pgfmathresult)
                         \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{\stC[1]}} to (\pgfmathresult);

    % method two
    \tikzmath{\first= \stC[0]; \second = \stC[1];}
    \draw[blue, bend right] (\first) to (\second);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** The array index starts with 0.

Comment: A slightly different approach for method two with the `evaluate` key: `\draw[evaluate={\first=\stC[0]; \second = \stC[1];}] (\first) to (\second);`

Comment: First approach works! :-)

Answer (score 3):

TikZ expects fully expandable input in coordinates and such things.
See for example (there are probably more):

- [How to draw a circle whose radius is a multiple of the distance of two points in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129606/16595)
- [Computing value using pgfmath for use in coordinates?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112457/16595)
- [\pgfmath and \foreach in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141259/16595)

---

With the `.evaluated` key handler and the `node` coordinate system used explicitly you can do:

```
\draw (node cs: name/.evaluated=\stC[1])
   -- (node cs: name/.evaluated=\stC[0]);
```

---

For actual coordinates (i.e. no node names), TikZ throws everything in PGFmath anyway, and you can just do

```
\newcommand*\stDA{{.5,2,3.4,-1.5}}
\newcommand*\stDB{{2,1.5,3,-1}}
\foreach \da in {0,2}
  \foreach \db in {0,2}
    \draw (\stDA[\da], \stDB[\db]) -- (\stDA[\da+1], \stDB[\db+1]);
```

Comment: By the way, `\pgfmathparse{<stuff>}\pgfmathresult` can otherwise shortened to `\pgfmathprint{<stuff>}`. (There's also `\pgfmathprintnumber`.)

Comment: Since 2019, PGFkeys comes with its own `.evaluated` key that uses the same definition (apart from some checks that PGFmath is actually loaded) as [`.pgfmath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/251438/2) from my previous answer.