# (x)ifthen in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, conditionals, foreach, xifthen

I am searching for a way to conditionally handle some items in a TikZ `\foreach` specially using an `\ifthenelse` condition. However, the compiler responds

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \isin
```

when processing this document.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xifthen}

\newcommand\groupedges[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \name/\position in {a/30, b/40, c/20}
      \node (\name) at (\position:5cm) {\name};
    \foreach \name/\position in {d/120, e/150, f/170, g/90, h/100}
      \node (\name) at (\position:5cm) {\name};
    \node (left) at (-1, 0) {left};
    \node (right) at (1, 0) {right};
    \foreach \name in {#1}
      \path (\ifthenelse{\isin{\name}{#2}}{right}{left}) edge (\name);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \groupedges{a,b,d,e,g,h}{abc}
\end{document}
```

I initially thought of expressing the conditional with pgfkeys, but found this to be too cumbersome, especially when used in a `\newcommand`, which I need for the more complex intended case this serves as an example for.

I also tried to implement it using pure TeX, which has an `\ifin@` conditional. This results in the same error.

Are TikZ and ifthen (or xifthen) combinable? Is there an easy pgfkeys or pure TeX solution? Or may there even be more suggestions to implement decisions on the `\foreach` elements?

Comment: You can’t unexpandable stuff in a coordinate expression, see: [Computing value using pgfmath for use in coordinates?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112457) and [How to draw a circle whose radius is a multiple of the distance of two points in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129606) and [Numbering nodes in a for loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132982)

Answer (score 4):

*edit (2017): second half of answer was broken since `xint 1.1 (2014/10/28)` as package `xint` does not load `xinttools` since then. Code updated to use directly package `xinttools`.*

Quite probably, the issue is with the (non) expandability of these tests. But you can do this [thanks to the moderator who corrected the `edge`, I had copied pasted from the OP without double-check]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xifthen}

\newcommand\groupedges[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \name/\position in {a/30, b/40, c/20}
      \node (\name) at (\position:5cm) {\name};
    \foreach \name/\position in {d/120, e/150, f/170, g/90, h/100}
      \node (\name) at (\position:5cm) {\name};
    \node (left) at (-1, 0) {left};
    \node (right) at (1, 0) {right};
    \foreach \name in {#1}
      {\ifthenelse{\isin{\name}{#2}}{\path (right) edge (\name);}
                                    {\path (left)  edge (\name);}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}%
  \groupedges{a,b,d,e,g,h}{abc}
\end{document}
```

(updated image)

> [image: ifthen1]

But, is apparent, this does not work as expected. I thus was sort of reluctantly coerced into again making propaganda for [xint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) `:)`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xifthen}
\usepackage{xinttools}

\newcommand\groupedges[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \name/\position in {a/30, b/40, c/20}
      \node (\name) at (\position:5cm) {\name};
    \foreach \name/\position in {d/120, e/150, f/170, g/90, h/100}
      \node (\name) at (\position:5cm) {\name};
    \node (left) at (-1, 0) {left};
    \node (right) at (1, 0) {right};
    % \foreach \name in {#1}
    %   {\ifthenelse{\isin{\name}{#2}}{\path (right) edge (\name);}
    %                                 {\path (left)  edge (\name);}}
    \xintFor ##1 in {#1}
    \do  {\ifthenelse{\isin{##1}{#2}}{\path (right)}
                                     {\path (left)}  edge (##1);}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}%
  \groupedges{a,b,d,e,g,h}{abc}
\end{document}
```

> [image: xifthen2]

Comment: The conditional does not seem to work right. All the nodes are still connected to `left`, while a and b should in fact be connected to `right`.

Comment: @XZS I had copied pasted the original code without double-checking so I did not become aware of the problem, sorry. It seems the problem is more with `\foreach` than with the conditional? I don't know, but I have added a method not using `\foreach`, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Two remarks :

- `\isin` seems impossible to put inside path command. So you have to do (as proposed by @jfbu) :

```
    {\ifthenelse{...}{\path (right) edge (\name);}
                     {\path (left)  edge (\name);}}
```

- to be able to use `\isin{\name}{#2}` you have to expand `\name` befor to pass it to `\isin` like this `\expandafter\isin\name{#2}` so finaly you can do this :

```
    {\ifthenelse{\expandafter\isin\name{#2}}{\path (right) edge (\name);}
                                            {\path (left)  edge (\name);}}
```

---

Here is the full code that works for me :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, xifthen}

\newcommand\groupedges[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \name/\position in {a/30, b/40, c/20}
      \node (\name) at (\position:5cm) {\name};
    \foreach \name/\position in {d/120, e/150, f/170, g/90, h/100}
      \node (\name) at (\position:5cm) {\name};
    \node (left) at (-1, 0) {left};
    \node (right) at (1, 0) {right};
    \foreach \name in {#1}
      {\ifthenelse{\expandafter\isin\name{#2}}{\path (right) edge (\name);}
                                    {\path (left)  edge (\name);}}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
  \groupedges{a,b,d,e,g,h}{abc}
\end{document}
```