# Why can't I get a conditional command to work in a macro invoked within a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, xstring

I wanted to create a macro that can be invoked in the middle of a tikz path and behave differently, conditional on one of the arguments.

Here is an example document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{ifthen, tikz}

\newcommand{\nameandlabel}[2]{%
    node [midway, \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{above}{below}] {#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale = 25mm]
    \node (a) at (0, 0) {$A$};
    \node (b) at (1, 0) {$B$};
    \node (c) at (2, 0) {$C$};
    \draw (a) -- (b) node [midway, above] {$f$};
    \draw (b) -- (c) \nameandlabel{a}{$g$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This document does not compile. It results in this error message, which is surprising because `\equal` is a macro provided by ifthen.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \equal 
                  {a}{a}
l.16     \draw (b) -- (c) \nameandlabel{a}{$g$}
                                               ;
```

I saw discussion on the TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange that said that ifthen was obsolete and that the `\IfStrEq` macro from the xstring package might be used instead. So I changed the example to the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{xstring, tikz}

\newcommand{\nameandlabel}[2]{%
    node [midway, \IfStrEq{#1}{a}{above}{below}] {#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale = 25mm]
    \node (a) at (0, 0) {$A$};
    \node (b) at (1, 0) {$B$};
    \node (c) at (2, 0) {$C$};
    \draw (a) -- (b) node [midway, above] {$f$};
    \draw (b) -- (c) \nameandlabel{a}{$g$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this results in an even more incomprehensible error message:

```
! Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.16     \draw (b) -- (c) \nameandlabel{a}{$g$}
                                               ;
```

Why does this still not work?

Comment: TikZ takes charge of parsing and expanding things in the paths so I guess in this case `\nameandlabel` does not get expanded before TikZ tries to make sense of the path. You may sidestep the problem by proper use of key-val: with `\tikzset{a/.style={above}, mystyle/.style={midway,below}}` you can do `...(c) node[mystyle,a] {$g$}` or `node[mystyle]` for defaulting to below...

Comment: Bordaigorl, the following macro works perfectly in my main document: \newcommand{\isomorphismDecoration}[2]{node [midway, #1 = -2.3mm] {$\widetilde{\phantom{#2}}$}}

Comment: Yes you are right, it seems to be a genuine conflict with the conditionals commands...just as a temporary workaround you could define `a` as an alias for `above` and then change the def of your macro to `node [midway, #1] {#2}`

Comment: Is using `\ifx` unacceptable? If you do not need anything fancier than checking it is an `a` than you could get away with `\ifx#1a{above}\else{below}\fi` (which does work in your code)

Comment: The `\IfStrEq` is not fully expandable (meaning it will leave traces besides `left` and `right` in the options which clutter up the key parser from PGFkeys). Similar to the problem in [(x)ifthen in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144885) (and related question). You will need to do conditional outside of the keys (either outside of the path, inside of `\pgfextra{…}` or with the `/utils/exec` key).

Comment: By the way, you are using `xscale` incorrectly. This key should only get a value, not a length. What you are essentially doing is `xscale=71.13188`. Why don’t you simply define a style with the name `a` (or similar) that is defined as `a/.style={above}`, another key like `b` for `below` can be defined as well. By the way, do you know the `auto` and the `swap` options/keys?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the document without paying much attention. It should be `x`, not `xscale` I guess. I decided the easiest thing to do is just to define two different macros. Actually, in the real task I wanted 4 different possibilities (above, below, left and right) so I just created 4 different macros.

Answer (score 3):

Neither `ifthen` nor `xstring` tests work by *expansion* they both make internal definitions.

If you use a purely expandable test it works as you had intended.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{ifthen, tikz}

\newcommand{\nameandlabel}[2]{%
    node [midway, \ifx a#1above\else below\fi] {#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x = 25mm]
    \node (a) at (0, 0) {$A$};
    \node (b) at (1, 0) {$B$};
    \node (c) at (2, 0) {$C$};
    \draw (a) -- (b) node [midway, above] {$f$};
    \draw (b) -- (c) \nameandlabel{a}{$g$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x = 25mm]
    \node (a) at (0, 0) {$A$};
    \node (b) at (1, 0) {$B$};
    \node (c) at (2, 0) {$C$};
    \draw (a) -- (b) node [midway, above] {$f$};
    \draw (b) -- (c) \nameandlabel{b}{$g$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The David Carlisle's answer is a direct answer to your question.
But I think that in your case in place to use conditional it is more in the spirit of Ti*k*Z to use a `.is choice` key handler. Here is an example how to do it.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  ab/.is choice,
  ab/a/.style={above},
  ab/b/.style={below},
}
\newcommand{\nameandlabel}[2]{%
    node [midway,ab=#1] {#2}%
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x = 25mm]
      \node (a) at (0, 0) {$A$};
      \node (b) at (1, 0) {$B$};
      \node (c) at (2, 0) {$C$};
      \draw (a) -- (b) node [midway, above] {$f$};
      \draw (b) -- (c) \nameandlabel{a}{$g$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x = 25mm]
      \node (a) at (0, 0) {$A$};
      \node (b) at (1, 0) {$B$};
      \node (c) at (2, 0) {$C$};
      \draw (a) -- (b) node [midway, above] {$f$};
      \draw (b) -- (c) \nameandlabel{b}{$g$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]